# Turn on/off Safari private browsing mode

Tags: browser

Where do I go to turn on/off the private browsing mode in safari on my I-phone? I'm trying to get on Tigerdroppings website and my log in will not work. I was told to turn off my private browsing but I cannot find where it is to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to open the Safari *Panels* menu in your iPhone (the tabs menu, looking like two superposed rectangles in the lower right corner of your screen). You will see a highlighted *Private* square on the lower left corner of your screen. Tap it and there you go!